# Use of unresolved identifier: "UNMutableNotificationContent"

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, unnotificationrequest

I have the following code:

```
func sendLucidNotification() {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "10 Second Notification Demo"
    content.subtitle = "From MakeAppPie.com"
    content.body = "Notification after 10 seconds - Your pizza is Ready!!"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "message"

}
```

When I call, UNMutableNotificationContent, or any "UNMutableNotification" variation I get the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier: "UNMutableNotificationContent"
```

I'm on Xcode 8.0, but when I try autocompleting it doesn't recognize it either. Any ideas ? Thank you!

Comment: Have you import `UserNotifications` framework?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most probably you need to add the import notification_framework statement where you have written this code e.g

```
import notification_framework_name
```

Also make sure the framework is available for your target build.

Update: in your case the import statement would be :

```
import UserNotifications
```

Comment: Nirav D. comments actually is the concrete answer. The answer above is a bit cryptic.

Comment: `#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>` in obj-c